# Plone 4.0: FormGen Mailer Template Fields

Tags: plone

I am customizing a form mailer template and would like the fields in my email template to be grouped by their fieldsets, and also include the fieldset title. Is that possible to do? Thank you in advance. I am a new user to Plone. My current template is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
     <p tal:content="here/getBody_pre | nothing" />
    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
        <tal:block repeat="field options/wrappedFields | nothing">
    <tr style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-color: black;">
<td>
<tal:first tal:content="field/fgField/widget/label" />: <tal:second tal:content="structure python:field.htmlValue(request)" />             
</td>
</tr>
    </tal:block>
</table>
<p tal:content="here/getBody_post | nothing" />
<pre tal:content="here/getBody_footer | nothing" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You will get better results if you ask on our forum https://community.plone.org